# How to make annotation to code listings

Tags: sourcecode, annotations

Is it possible to make annotations to source codes like below?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us the tex code you have so far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want two things:  (1) add footnotes to the listing, and (2) change the way footnotes look.  Lets us do both.

The package `fancyvrb` allows to add arbitrary TeX commands to a verbatim text.  So

```
\begin{Verbatim}[\commandchars=\\\{\}]
  text\footnote{this is a footnote}
\end{Verbatim}
```

will add a footnote to the verbatim snippet.  Since we want the footnotes to be close to the listing, let us put the snippet in the `minipage`, then footnotes automatically become minipage footnotes.  Now, you want footnote mark to be a dingbat, and to typeset footnote marks flush right.  The first is achieved by

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\ding{\numexpr(181+\c@mpfootnote)}}
\makeatother
```

the second by defining a special command

```
\newcommand{\commentcode}[1]{\hfill\footnote{#1}}
```

All together:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{pifont}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\ding{\numexpr(181+\c@mpfootnote)}}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\commentcode}[1]{\hfill\footnote{#1}}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gsl/gsl-1.16.tar.gz\commentcode{Download the zipped archive}
tar xzvf \commentcode{Unzip the archive}
cd gsl-1.16
./configure
make
sudo make install
\end{Verbatim}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Boris. This is it. I have one more question is it possible to add hyperlink from listing line to footnote and from footnote to the line of listing?

Comment: `\usepackage{hyperref}` will give you links from the code to comments